# FastReport trouble print

Tags: delphi, printing, fastreport

I am having trouble printing reports with FastReport in Delphi 2010.
When printing to the printer the first time, it prints correctly, but the second time that I try to print the report does not print correctly.

Viewing on my computer is working correctly, the problem is when I will print on the printer that the problem happens.

```
frxReport1.LoadFromFile(FileRep);

if isPrint then begin
  frxReport1.PrepareReport();
  frxReport1.Print;
end else
  frxReport1.ShowReport;
```

For exemple:

The wrong form (the first time): 
[image]

The correct form (the second time): 
[image]

Comment: I don't know what "printed in half" means. Can you [edit] to make the problem you're having more clear? Do you mean only half of the page is printed? Or do you mean that only page 1 is printed and not page 2 (or page 2 and not page 1)? Is the report connected to a dataset?

Comment: I put the photos of the problem. Is not connected to a dataset.

Comment: Your second photo is inaccessible from most proxy servers. It needs to be put on imgur like the first one.

Comment: I put the photo. I'm sorry.

Comment: Why a blurry cell phone photo of the first (half) report? Preview it like you did the second (full) report and do a proper screen capture. (*Please* don't make us beg you to give us the details we need to help you. If it becomes more work to get the information from you than it will be to solve the problem, people will just stop trying to help you and move on to help someone else.)

Comment: Viewing on my computer is working correctly, the problem is when I will print on the printer that the problem happens. The sheet printed for the first time prints correctly (second photo), but the second time does not print more correctly (first photo), it prints according to the photo of the phone. Maybe it might be my printer's problem, I do not know how to say it as this happens with all system reports not just this one. I need to close and re-open the system so it prints correctly. My printer is the HP Officejet J3680 All-in-One. BTW it's my hand, my fingers.

Comment: I have scanned the sheet that is printed, to better visualize what is happening. I'm sorry for my lack of professionalism.

Comment: do you get the same results with a PDF printer? A different printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use latest FR 5.5.11. If problem still exists - create small demo project with error and send it to FR's support https://support.fast-report.com/tickets